# Can I attach/embed a file to a Latex document and hyperlink it to a word for saving purposes?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am trying to attach a .condarc file to my Latex journal as an installation guide. I want users for my workshop to click on a hyperlink and be able to save/download the file. Is this possible through Latex in general? What about on Overleaf?

I've looked all over the place, however there seem to only be file specific packages. 
I tried using the embedfile and attachfile packages. Here's an example of what I did:

```
\usepackage{embedfile}

\embedfile[
    desc={Source of Package 'embedfile'}

]{.condarc }
```

I did the above because I thought the first step is to get the file embedded somewhere, anywhere. Then I could reference the file in later steps.

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: "They didn't end up working." is not a very helpful description. Can you show us what you tried and the problems you faced?

Comment: @samcarter my apologies. The original post was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a pdf viewer that supports attachments (e.g. adobe reader) the following example using the `attachfile` package will attach the `.codarc` file to the pdf and produce a text link that will prompt the user for future action:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{attachfile}

\begin{document}

test \textattachfile[color=1 0 0]{.codarc}{.codarc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(please be aware that even if a pdf viewer might be technically equipped to open such embedded files, users may have this feature disabled due to security concerns)

---

Instead of attaching the file, one could also host it somewhere on the internet and put a link into the pdf. This will work for a much larger variety of pdf viewers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

test 

\href{https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samcarter/tikzducks/master/LICENSE.txt}{LICENSE.txt}

\end{document}
```